# Prevent inclusion of mean in boxplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, legend-properties

In ggplot2 boxplot with added mean, is there a way to prevent the mean from being 
included with the legend? I must use a large point size and find its
inclusion in the legend distracting.  The conceptually closest problem
I could find, for removing the slash from the legend of *outlined* bar charts, is
at

[http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/#modifying-the-legend-box](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/#modifying-the-legend-box)

That solution uses geom_bar twice to overlay one plot on another, the second, outlined 
 bar chart, without a legend.  But is there a solution for preventing
 the mean from appearing in the boxplot legend?

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", shape=18, size=3) + 
#  idea from above website
geom_boxplot(show_guide=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add argument `show_guide=FALSE` inside the `stat_summary()` call to prevent placing of points inside the legend.

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
                         shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the shape from the boxplot legend and add it as a new legend to the plot then you can use:

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group))+ 
geom_boxplot() + 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, aes(colour="mean"), geom="point", shape=18, size=3)+
scale_color_manual(name="",values = "darkred")+
scale_fill_nejm(name="Group",guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape="")))
```